# What is the relation between modal base and ordering source?

Tags: semantics, theoretical-linguistics, modality

I edited the question again. Here is an explanation for epistemic modal,

John **must** have the flu.

a. Epistemic Modal Base (MBepis) = { John has a fever, John has a cough, John did not get a flu shot, ...}

b. Doxastic/Streotypical Ordering Source (OSdx/st) = {Flu leads to a fever, Many people in town are suffering from flu right now,
People suffering from the same symptoms in the same town all have the same
disease, ... } (Portner 2009:pp.64-65)

I just can't figure out what is the difference between modal base and ordering source? It seems like they're both a set of propositions right? Do they have any relation?
And what does it mean "modal base and ordering source are both function from worlds to sets of propositions"?

Comment: You really need to explain a lot more in your question. For example, readers need to know that you’re asking about Angelica Kratzer’s theory of modals.

Comment: I don't know the theory you're asking about, but it strikes me that set a contains observations about John and set b contains general knowledge / assumptions that lead you from those observations to the conclusion that John has the flu. Since your conclusion is then an evidence-based inference it's appropriate to use "must". There looks to be something missing from your last sentence but it may just mean that the elements in both sets are abstractions.

Comment: @rchivers Thank you for your kind explanation which makes it much clearer! Thank you so much!